# DOM equivalent for SVG elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I am trying to create tags under SVG using DOM and i needed some help on the same. I am not able to figure out how to set attributes for "rect" tags. The below is the snapshot of the HTML code. I would like to create the same using DOM.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" width ="1500" height="1500">
        <text x="0" y="15" fill="black">AISLE A</text>

         <rect x=10 y=45 rx="10" ry="10" width="40" height="40" style="fill:red;stroke:black;opacity:0.5" onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 'black'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 5;" onmouseout="this.style.stroke = '#000000'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;">
          <title id="title1">
            Location: FP-A-02</br>Replenrate: xx%</br>PickRate: yy%
          </title>
          </rect>

          <rect x=60 y=45 rx="10" ry="10" width="40" height="40" style="fill:red;stroke:black;opacity:0.5" onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 'black'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 5;" onmouseout="this.style.stroke = '#000000'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;">
          <title  id="title2">
            Location: FP-A-02</br>Replenrate: xx%</br>PickRate: yy%
          </title>
          </rect>
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="black">AISLE B</text>     
          <rect x=110 y=45 rx="10" ry="10" width="40" height="40" style="fill:red;stroke:black;opacity:0.5" onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 'black'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 5;" onmouseout="this.style.stroke = '#000000'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;">
          <title  id="title3">
            Location: FP-A-02</br>Replenrate: xx%</br>PickRate: yy%
          </title>
          </rect>

          <rect x=160 y=45 rx="10" ry="10" width="40" height="40" style="fill:red;stroke:black;opacity:0.5" onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 'black'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 5;" onmouseout="this.style.stroke = '#000000'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;">
          <title  id="title4">
            Location: FP-A-02</br>Replenrate: xx%</br>PickRate: yy%
          </title>
          </rect>
<svg>
```

Please note that there are 2 AISLES A and B. I would be creating 20 rectangles within each AISLES. Creating them manually is not an optimized way and hence wanted to use DOM to create elements.

Comment: You can use D3.js, it specializes in this stuff :)

Comment: Not that comfortable with D3. Is there any links that i can refer and do this

Comment: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch03.html this whole book is awesome source to get started, but this particular chapter will help you do the thing that you want to do. :)

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the svg tags like any other DOM element. For instance:

```
// Create the SVG from scratch or get one already on your DOM
// For sake of example, here we create one.
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
// Same logic for the inner tags
var rect = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'rect');

// Once you have reference to the element, setting attributes is simple.
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute
rect.setAttribute('x', 0);
// ...

// At the end you append all your child elements to the parent
svg.appendChild(rect);
// ...
```

Comment: SVG elements cannot be created by createElement, you must use creatElementNS to create them in the SVG namespace.

Comment: Ah yes! you are right @RobertLongson. Fixed the create element for the SVG. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You need to fix the rect too in the same way.

Comment: ... and I learn while trying to answer a question haha, thanks @RobertLongson

Comment: Thank you guys.. will try this now